# UITextField validations

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am beginner in Ios in my project i am crating one registration page and there i have to provide validations for textfields as like best level and i have searched for this so many  textfield validations tutorials but i did not get correct one

According to my requirement when i clicked on textfield if there is any error then need to show alert message on textfields like below screen for this i have written so many custom methods but they are not working please help me some one

[image]

Comment: There is way too little information to go on. Maybe post a link to your project? Tell us what you tried and what didn't work specifically, etc. At this point, you might try searching for open source iOS libraries and/or tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your custom view for validate the textFields

You can try to do it with https://github.com/ustwo/US2FormValidator

Code in reference to Objective-C

```
US2ValidatorTextField *firstNameTextField  = [[US2ValidatorTextField alloc] init];
firstNameTextField.validator               = [[[MyProjectValidatorName alloc] init] autorelease];
firstNameTextField.shouldAllowViolation    = YES;
firstNameTextField.validateOnFocusLossOnly = YES;
firstNameTextField.placeholder             = @"Enter first name";
firstNameTextField.validatorUIDelegate     = self;
[_textUICollection addObject:firstNameTextField];
[firstNameTextField release];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: that above git hub code having too much data and also it's too difficult to edit that

Comment: @Ramakrishna Humm, There too many libraries available. take it as reference.

Answer (score 1):

I've written many `UITextField` validators and its always best to do this sort of thing yourself as each requirement is different and there is more control over it.

The best time to validate is normally when `UItextField` did end editing - this way you know the user is done.

You need to look at `UITextField`s `delegate` methods and use the `text` argument from there to check length and that sort of thing.

I can't supply any code as you haven't stated what sort of validation you want done. If its email - this is the sort of thing you need (Its in Objective-C though)

```
  /* Email address validation test */
    NSString *emailReg = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg];

    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailAddress]){
            validEmail = YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its like you can implement this with simple code as like checking and showing an alert.

- if the textfield is empty
- if the textfield contains numbers
- if the textfield is a email field
- if the all the required text field is filled

you can achieve this by using this piece of code

```
// To check the email field is not empty string

    if([[self.email text] isEqualToString:@""]){

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Enter your email!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
// To check the email field has '@' empty string
    else if ([self.email.text rangeOfString:@"@"].location == NSNotFound){
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Enter proper email!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
```

you can implement like this or you can use libraries depending on your requirement.

Comment: i want to show alert like above image

Comment: https://github.com/BenjaminSarkisyan/BSErrorMessageView check this link i found you the code that you want for... use this library